# Simple ejb client app (servlet) using JNDI architecture.

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, servlets

I'm tryng to build a simple "Hello World" app using EJB's and Servlet. I'm strongly confused about how it should look like. I have two projects in eclipse. One contains EJB Stateless session bean and its interface (both of them in this same package) the other one contains bean, interface and servlet which should be able to call both beans methods. I've added the remote project (from the other project) to "Projects" in build path. Now i've imported the remote interfaces to the servlet. Now the servlet looks like this:

```
import pl.test.IHelloRemote;
import pl.other.IDateRemote;

@WebServlet("/TestServlet")
public class Control extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private InitialContext ic;
    private IHelloRemote iHelloRemote;
    private IDateRemote iDateRemote;

    public Control() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            ic = new InitialContext();
            iHelloRemote = ic.lookup ("java:global/test-project/HelloBean!pl.test.iHelloRemote");
            iDateRemote = ic.lookup ("java:global/other-project/DateBean!pl.other.iDateRemote");
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        iHelloRemote.sayHello();
        iDateRemote.getDate();
    }
}
```

As I mention the "other-project" is included in the build path. Here's how the single bean that I want to use looks  like:

```
package pl.other;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
public class DateBean implements IDateRemote {

    public DateBean() {}

    @Override
    public void getDate {
        //some code here
    }
}
```

Now my questions.

Why (and how to fix that) during deployment i get error: 
Class [ Lpl/other/IDateRemote; ] not found. Error while loading [ class TestServlet]

Can EJB beans be located in default package? Why Elipse does'nt allows that?

Where shall bean interfaces be located? In the same package as bean? In the Servlet package? What is the "best practice" setup of the files in this kind of project?
As for now the setup is like follows:

```
test-project
|- (default package)
  |- TestServlet
|- pl.test
  |- IHelloRemote
  |- HelloBean

other-project
|- pl.other
  |- IDateRemote
  |- DateBean
```

Thank You for replies and patience. 
Smok.

Comment: How are you running it? is that you running from within eclipse?

Comment: Well, yes. I do. But I'm not the only one to run it, and I know, that the other person (my teacher) will compile and deploy this test app manually. That what worries me about using the packages.